# What is about this weird "it DO n't"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

This is the second time i hear songs with **it don't** instead of **it doesn't**. The first time i thought that it is just music and the singer made that change in order to let it fit

This is the first song
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMwcoaZNauQ

but now even Adele in here new `Hello` song, she says it don't

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQHsXMglC9A

What is going on? is that normal? is it like old English rule? or just because of the music ?

**As always: It is not duplicated for that question (listed) this is about it not about he.**

Comment: [*It don't matter to me*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it+don%27t+matter+to+me%22) was the title of a 1969 track by *Bread*, but that will account for only a tiny fraction of almost 5000 written instances of the usage in Google Books. It's perfectly normal in relaxed colloquial contexts for many native speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers really? it is correct? OMG these songs make me say don't instead of doesn't

Comment: @FumbleFingers really duplicated?

Comment: It "ain't" matter to use "don't". But only colloquially.

Comment: @William: Define "correct". The fact that you've *asked* about the usage strongly suggests you're not a native speaker, but if you were to actually *use* it in a real-world situation, no-one would make any such assumption.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There is a [similar question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154355/he-doesnt-vs-he-dont) that could shed some light on the situation. According to the user who answered the question above, it's _not_ correct in General American English. As to why she used it in the song, that's pure speculation. It may have fit better rhythmically, or she may be trying to make the song more accessible by appealing to a larger audience.

Comment: I agree with what's been said here, though. The arguably incorrect (strictly speaking) usage of **don't** is quite common in multiple regions in the U.S., but only in colloquial cases, or in places where it's become ingrained with the regional accent.

Comment: @arbitrarystringofletters You should not say those who use it are not correct. It is being used colloquially together with "we was, there is/was a plural noun", etc.

Comment: @arbitrarystringofletters: Obviously the third-person singular for ***to do*** is ***does***, which contracts in the negative to ***doesn't***. Arguably asking about that would be Off Topic even on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). So if your definition of "correct" means "endorsed by formal grammar tutorials", OP's cited usage is "incorrect". But it's a perfectly common usage, even if it don't follow "the rules". And in relaxed casual speech (with a schwa for the vowel) it would often be impossible to hear whether there was a partially-articulated ***s*** in there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - That's all I'm trying to point out. I'm not judging people who use the construction, or even saying it shouldn't be used. I am simply providing the "endorsed by formal grammar tutorials" opinion for what it is. I apologize if my previous responses came off as judgemental; they were only intended to be informative.

Comment: It's not correct in standard American English, but it is extremely common in the African-American Vernacular English. Music has been strongly influenced by black musicians/singers in the U.S., and generally uses colloquial rather than formal language, which explains why it is extremely common in songs.

Comment: @arbitrarystringofletters: ELU is for [linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which I understand to mean we can expect everyone here to be familiar with the basic grammar of English. In principle there might be a valid question here regarding *how acceptable, and in what contexts* deviations from "standard" grammar arise, but that's probably just a matter of opinion anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Agreed. I think this question is a matter of prescriptive versus descriptive language, which is a discussion that will continue for many many years and certainly won't be resolved today.

Comment: It's a duplicate. *he don't, it don't, that don't, she don't, a man don't, John don't,* ... are ***all*** the same vernacular grammar and all have the same answer. It don't make sense to have a separate question for each of them.

Comment: If only people wouldn't worry so much about whether song lyrics are violating the rules. I sometimes wonder what they think the penalty is, and how it's enforced.

Comment: @John Lawler: It's a (minuscule) *financial* penalty (fusspots refuse to buy their records). Probably more than offset by all the other people who think *Hey! That singer talk just like me! I don't like the music, but I'll buy it to show linguistic solidarity!*

Comment: @FF: There's probly one of each. Some penalty. Much the same can be said of non-native speakers worrying about whether native speakers are violating `The Rules`.

Answer (score 3):

*It don't* (exactly like *He don't*, *She don't* and *That thing don't*) is not grammatical in current standard English, but it is found in many colloquial variants. (A hundred and fifty years ago upper-class English speakers used it, but they generally don't now).